# Transforme and exists to merge into

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I want to transform this request too slow into Merge into but I have two conditions and exists how I can not transform the request correctly

initial request

```
UPDATE DR_POS pos
  set MtIntInterPer = (select max(MtFlx) from DR_ECH_OPE ech
                       where ech.DateCurrent = '03/01/2019' AND ech.IdOpe = pos.IdOpe AND ech.IdJmb = pos.IdJmb AND ech.CdTypOpe = pos.CdTypOpe AND ech.CdTypFlx in ('INT', 'IPR') 
                       and ech.DtVal=pos.DtProPaiInt)
  where datecurrent = '03/01/2019'  AND CdEtab = 'BPCE'
  AND exists (select 1 from DR_ECH_OPE ech
              where ech.DateCurrent = '03/01/2019' AND ech.IdOpe = pos.IdOpe AND ech.IdJmb = pos.IdJmb AND ech.CdTypOpe = pos.CdTypOpe AND ech.CdTypFlx in ('INT', 'IPR') 
              and ech.DtVal=pos.DtProPaiInt )
  AND exists (select 1 from DR_ECH_OPE ech
              where ech.DateCurrent = '03/01/2019' AND ech.IdOpe = pos.IdOpe AND ech.IdJmb = pos.IdJmb AND ech.CdTypOpe = pos.CdTypOpe AND ech.CdTypFlx in ('INT', 'IPR')   
              and DtFinPer=pos.DTARRETE);
```

my request that I tried to test but it does not return me the same number of line:

```
 MERGE INTO dr_pos pos USING (
                                SELECT
                                    MAX(ech.mtflx) max_mtflx,
                                    ech.datecurrent,
                                    ech.idope,
                                    ech.idjmb,
                                    ech.cdtypope,
                                    ech.cdtypflx,
                                    ech.dtval,
                                    ech.dtfinper
                                FROM
                                    dr_ech_ope ech
                                WHERE
                                    ech.datecurrent = '03/01/2019'
                                    AND ech.cdtypflx IN (
                                        'INT',
                                        'IPR'
                                    )
                                GROUP BY
                                    ech.datecurrent,
                                    ech.idope,
                                    ech.idjmb,
                                    ech.cdtypope,
                                    ech.cdtypflx,
                                    ech.dtval,
                                    ech.dtfinper
                            )
ech ON ( pos.datecurrent = '03/01/2019'
         AND pos.cdetab = 'BPCE'
         AND ech.idope = pos.idope
         AND ech.idjmb = pos.idjmb
         AND ech.cdtypope = pos.cdtypope
         AND ech.dtval = pos.dtpropaiint
         AND ech.dtfinper = pos.dtarrete )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET mtintinterper = max_mtflx;
```

Comment: i would like transformer my request with 2 and existe ion Merge into for ameliorate the performence, first reques

Comment: oracle database  11g

Answer (score 0):

**I found the solution and I gained a lot of time in terms of performance**

```
Merge into  DR_POS pos
using (select max(ech.MtFlx) max_mtflx ,ech.IdOpe,ech.IdJmb ,ech.CdTypOpe,ech.DtVal 
                       from DR_ECH_OPE ech 
                       where ech.DateCurrent = '03/01/2019'   AND ech.CdTypFlx in ('INT', 'IPR')  
                       group by  ech.IdOpe, ech.IdJmb, ech.CdTypOpe,ech.DtVal 
                       ) ech
on( pos.datecurrent = '03/01/2019'  AND pos.CdEtab = 'BPCE' and ech.IdOpe = pos.IdOpe AND ech.IdJmb = pos.IdJmb AND ech.CdTypOpe = pos.CdTypOpe and ech.DtVal=pos.DtProPaiInt 
              AND exists (select 1 from DR_ECH_OPE ech2
              where ech2.DateCurrent = '03/01/2019' AND ech2.IdOpe = pos.IdOpe AND ech2.IdJmb = pos.IdJmb AND ech2.CdTypOpe = pos.CdTypOpe   AND ech2.CdTypFlx in ('INT', 'IPR') 
              and ech2.DtFinPer=pos.DTARRETE))
when matched then 
update set pos.MtIntInterPer= ech.max_mtflx  ;
```